# in search of a Formula for ratio where one element is 0

Tags: ratio

Very nice to meet you all. I am searching to find the value x for the given image. its a ratio that looks like this:

```
0: 1 = 350 : Y
```

but this leads if we solve for Y:

```
0 * Y = 350 * 1

Y = 350/0
```

which is undefined.

[image]

How can i get the Y value in such a case for this ratio ?

UPDATE: THE 0 in the image represents an offset start. so i am giving an offset from 0 to 1 (or if you like 0% to 100%).   the orange numbers is my new offset i have created, it runs from 350 to Y.

UPDATE2:

[image]

There is this green box that i can drag up and down...
when this green box is collapsed as it is now in the below image near                                     the bottom, the dragOffset is defined as 0. so to be clear, collapsed box has offset of 0 ALWAYS.

as the box gets dragged towards the top, the offset keeps increasing from 0 until finally it hits the top which is a max offset of 1. So to be clear, the dragging offset from collapsed to expanded is numbers between [0,1].

Here is the image so you can see the transition. how the dragOffset is being delivered to me:

[image]

I have the ability to make the greenbox 60% of the total height like this:
[image]

*but when it reaches 60% the system is giving me a value such as 0.6 for the top, But at this point i can consider 60% as the FULL HEIGHT.  So the system thinks the full height is 1 but i want the full height to be at 0.6 (or 60%) mark*

**so to be clear, **i am searching for a way to SCALE the dragOffsets values called Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Yz  such that dragging from 0 to 0.6 would be the same as dragging from 0 to 1 in the system.  Hope it's clear now .**

Comment: 0 and 1 seem to be points; what are 350 and Y ?

Comment: $\dfrac 0 1 = \dfrac {350}{y}$ is undefined because there is no value for $y$ such that $0 y = 350$.

Comment: The picture is really odd: Something in the lower corner is $0$, and in the upper corner it's $1$. What is this something? Where did you get this picture? Did you make it yourself? If you made it yourself, perhaps it would be a good idea to make a clearer picture.

Comment: i updated the comments in a update section.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to calculate this? What is the context, and what is it that you need to calculate exactly? Also, in the picture, it's not really clear what the relationship between the distances is. The $Y$ and $350$ seem to be just floating in random spots ...

Comment: ok, wait a while let me create another image to explain it.

Comment: i made some updates to show what i need

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to map the interval $[0,1]$ to the interval $[350,Y]$.

The scale factor of your mapping is given by $\frac{Y-350}{1-0}=\frac{Y-350}{1}$, but you can't work out $Y$ without some more information about your new interval.

Comment: can you check my latest update to see if it helps, yes i want a scale factor i can apply to Y

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what you mean.